# How does the number of views increase for each question

Tags: discussion, views

Bearing in mind a get request shouldn't change data : [Why shouldn't a GET request change data on the server?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/188860/2297)

Comment: SO is not a REST API.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods

Comment: @Linuxios that "rule" is not specific to rest, but http in general

Comment: The post isn't changed on GET. The views counter is additional data provided after log analysis. What is the actual problem here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the number of views is part of the viewed post, and it changes after a get request. I have no problem with it at all, but others in the link do, judging by the answers.

Comment: Do you have an actual *problem* here or are you just criticizing the SE devs for not being purist enough? When you log in all the pages show *your* username because you do a GET with the correct cookie. Is that changing the page? Every time you request the page *your reputation* is shown as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters huh ? I was just interested. I am not critizing anyone, and I have no *problem*. I thought maybe it was an ajax post requests that got the data  ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky: SO also has a very strict viewcounter, not just a GET: views++;.

Comment: I quote from the wikipage you link: "...they should not have side effects, beyond relatively harmless effects such as logging, caching, the serving of banner advertisements or incrementing a web counter."

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: Exactly, "... **incrementing a web counter** ".

Comment: @Linuxios well maybe someone would like to post that as a very interesting answer. Would make better reading than these rather argumentative comments.

Comment: @Linuxios: Well, that leads to a new fun game: How high is your web count...on your toilet?!

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Apologies if I took the tone of your post to be more agressive than you intended; but your post *is* lacking context and detail, really.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: Um... Ok? (I think?)

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand the question here. The question you linked is specifically regarding API design, and not a website. The `Views` counter really doesn't impact that much on the site, aside from a couple of minor badges (tumbleweed, popular question, etc.).

I could understand if the view-count was used in a much more prominent way throughout the site, but since it isn't, and I like the view counter, I don't GET a problem here.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem since it was tagged discussion instead of bug. Maybe OP just wants to know how it works? But +1 for `I don't GET a problem here`  :)